# Python sort words based on last 2 letters

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

I have a list of words where I want to sort based on their last (2,3) letters. In other words if we say (Sort by Words ending with)

Following things I already tried aren't working for me. Maybe it requires a single more argument or needs a separate method for sorting.

```
mlist = sorted(mlist, key=lambda x: x[-2])
```

Here is a original list:

```
shoat
tubal
eclat
olam
stat
gnar
babai
scoad
scrap
```

If sorted by last two letters, it should be turned into this:

```
scoad
babai
tubal
olam
scrap
gnar
shoat
eclat
stat
```

If sorted with last three letters, it Should be turned into this

```
babai
tubal
olam
eclat
gnar
scoad
shoat
scrap
stat
```

Comment: Use `x[-2:]` instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must be using `sorted(words, key = lambda x:x[-2:])`, take the last two. You were using "take the second last".

Output

```
['scoad', 'babai', 'tubal', 'olam', 'scrap', 'gnar', 'shoat', 'eclat', 'stat']
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `x[-2:]` instead of `x[-2]`. Here I write a function with the number of characters as parameter:

```py
def sort_by_ending(mlist, char_num):
    return sorted(mlist, key = lambda x:x[-char_num:])

mlist = ['shoat', 'tubal', 'eclat', 'olam', 'stat', 'gnar', 'babai', 'scoad', 'scrap']

print(sort_by_ending(mlist, 2))
# ['scoad', 'babai', 'tubal', 'olam', 'scrap', 'gnar', 'shoat', 'eclat', 'stat']

print(sort_by_ending(mlist, 3))
# ['babai', 'tubal', 'olam', 'eclat', 'gnar', 'scoad', 'shoat', 'scrap', 'stat']
```